# How to stop the task ruby from running?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

So, the idea is if any task fails, as too much is not performed anymore.

Example: rails db: drop gives an error if there are any users logged into the database

Example: import_package gives an error if it doesn't have the .csv file or is different.

**this is dev task:**

```
require 'csv'

namespace :dev do

  desc "Configuration of the development environment."
  task setup: :environment do
    if Rails.env.development?
      show_spinner("Deleting database...") { %x(rails dev:drop_db) }
      show_spinner("Creating database...") { %x(rails db:create) }
      show_spinner("Running migrates...") { %x(rails db:migrate) }
      show_spinner("Importing Packages...") { %x(rails dev:import_packages) }
      show_spinner("Importing Products...") { %x(rails dev:import_products) }
      show_spinner("Running seeds...") { %x(rails db:seed) }
    else
      puts "You are not in a development environment."
    end
  end

  desc "Import packages from csv file"
  task import_packages: :environment do
    file = "db/packages.csv"

    CSV.foreach(file, :headers => true) do |row|
      Package.create!(row.to_hash)
    end
  end

  desc "Import Products from csv file"
  task import_products: :environment do
    file = "db/products.csv"

    CSV.foreach(file, :headers => true) do |row|
      Product.create!(row.to_hash)
    end
  end

  # Spinner load method
  def show_spinner(start_msg, end_msg = "Finished.")
    spinner = TTY::Spinner.new("[:spinner] #{start_msg}")
    spinner.auto_spin
    yield
    spinner.success("#{end_msg}")
  end
end
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Use [exceptions](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_exceptions.html) or throw.

Comment: can you help me with an example?

Comment: desc "Drop o db"
  task drop_db: :environment do
    begin 
      %x(rails db:drop)
    rescue StandardError => msg  
      puts msg
    end
  end

not running